# Store Image into bitmap in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have this problem where I want to store an image into bitmap using Open File Dialog in vb.net. How to achieve this?

I have this code:

```
Dim image1 As Bitmap
Private Sub add_image_LinkClicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles add_image.LinkClicked

    With OpenFileDialog1
        .Filter = ("Images | *.png; *.bmp; *.jpg;")
        .FilterIndex = 2
    End With
    OpenFileDialog1.FileName = "Select Image"
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
       image1 = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    End If
End Sub
```

I receive an error in `image1 = OpenFileDialog1.FileName`, I know this is wrong. Is there a way to store the selected image in `OpenFileDialog1` to `image1`?

Comment: What are you using the Bitmap for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
image1 = Image.FromFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
```

Comment: @Rak: And if you specifically want a Bitmap from it (which derives from the `Image` class) Then you can use `Dim Bmp As New Bitmap(Image)` or `Dim Bmp As New Bitmap(Image, Size)`if you want it a specific size.